# Not able to trigger action on AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function that sends some date to another page that inputs it into db. When input is complete on the second page I put a response:

```
echo 'phoneAdded';
```

I seem to be getting the response back but I am not able to trigger another function based on it...

```
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/addNewPhoneNumber.ajax',
            data: {
                'bid' : bid,
                'nbr' : newNum
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.status === 'phoneAdded') {
                    // phone stored in db
                    alert('Successfully added.');
                    });
                } else if(response.status === 'phoneExists') {
                    // phone already in db
                     alert('Sorry, this phone is already in use.');
                }
            }
        });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `console.log(response)` once. So that you can get idea of what is inside of it..

Comment: The response string `phoneAdded` is not valid JSON, and it certainly doesn't have a `status` property. Perhaps you meant to respond `echo '{ "status": "phoneAdded" }'`?

Comment: The above code isn't missing anything - it's got too much!  Remove the line after the first alert --> `});`  If that doesn't fix it then you may need an error handler.  Check the console for errors (500 error, for example)

Comment: @apsillers, you've got it, why don't you post this as an answer so that I could give you some credit!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `});` after the alert. Format like so:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/addNewPhoneNumber.ajax',
     data: {
         'bid': bid,
             'nbr': newNum
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (response) {
         if (response.status === 'phoneAdded') {
             // phone stored in db
             alert('Successfully added.');
         } else if (response.status === 'phoneExists') {
             // phone already in db
             alert('Sorry, this phone is already in use.');
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, it was just a typo. }); was just a remnant of my actual code. I was not getting any errors, but indeed my response was not a valid json, like @apsillers mentioned.